# What is the big O notation of the Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe algorithm (n-th hexadecimal digit of Pi)?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity, pi

If I want to compute the n-th hexadecimal digit of Pi with
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe_formula

what is the big O notation 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

for the Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe algorithm?

Comment: *waits for Mysticial to appear*

Comment: the n-th hexadecimal digit?

Comment: yes the n-th hexadecimal digit. I added "hexadecimal" to the post.

Comment: If you read the Wikipedia page to which you point us you will find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

In [the paper](http://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/digits.pdf) the upper bound of `O(n log^3(n))` bit complexity is presented for calculations of the digits of `log(2)`. Since they present a more generic formula later on, which also covers pi, I would think that it won't differ much from the above upper bound. But I haven't verified that.